# I can get you to many places. Guess what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I can get you to many places you want to be.
But you have to give me a pull or push when I meet T.

People do not write on me, unless I am accompanied by D.
In that case, my name is often written together with E.

Most of my kind cannot swim.
But when I join P, we shall live happily in a stream.

If you want to work with me, all you need is a key.
But when I am following S, you may want to get rid of me.

What am I?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> CAR

is the answer. Add T and you get:

> CART

which is pushed or pulled. Add D and you get:

> CARD

which people write on.  If you are writing one of those you likely

> CARE

about the person.

> CARP

swim. You want to get rid of a

> SCAR.

Comment: +1 from me because you did get there first, regardless of formatting.

Comment: Reverted, +1 nicely done.

Comment: yes, well I didn't want to make a fuss really :p good job!

Answer (score 6):

> SVN

I can get you to many places you want to be.

> You can Browse all the directories ie. you can go anywhere

But you have to give me a pull or push when I meet T.

> When Users Commit the changes in Trunk you need to Pull or Push New changes in Trunk

People do not write on me, unless I am accompanied by D.

> We can't Commit Until we write the complete Description of the changes.

In that case, my name is often written together with E.

> If changes commited then it will be written by svn:Explaination

Most of my kind cannot swim.

> Many user who doesn't have updated copy can't commit.

But when I join P, we shall live happily in a stream.

> If we have Present copy then can commit easily(join new data with Present copy will leave Happily).

If you want to work with me, all you need is a key.

> We Need a Password for Using it / or Version Number.

But when I am following S, you may want to get rid of me.

> Following Seurity Issues

Comment: Original riddle is easy, but this answer is really a different. +1

Comment: This is not right => "We can't Commit Until we write the complete Description of the changes."
I have been using SVN...

Answer (score 4):

You are a:

> CAR

I can get you to many places you want to be.

> Speaks for itself

But you have to give me a pull or push when I meet T.

> CAR - T

People do not write on me, unless I am accompanied by D.

> CAR - D

In that case, my name is often written together with E.

> CAR - E?

Most of my kind cannot swim.
But when I join P, we shall live happily in a stream.

> CAR - P

If you want to work with me, all you need is a key.

> a CAR KEY is needed to operate it

But when I am following S, you may want to get rid of me.

> S - CAR

Comment: my answer is better!!

Comment: Yes, but slower!

Comment: @randal'thor bah, whatever

Comment: How is this better?  It is the same answer but you copy and pasted the question into the answer without additional explanation.